# MongoDB -> turn embedded array of objects into embedded object of objects

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation

I have a field that is an array of objects embedded in a mongoDB document. I trying to turn that array into an object. The field is currently ->

```
skus: ARRAY
  >0: OBJECT
  >1: OBJECT
  >2: OBJECT
  >3: OBJECT
```

I would like it too be ->

```
skus: OBJECT
  >0: OBJECT
  >1: OBJECT
  >2: OBJECT
  >3: OBJECT
```

This is the aggregation that I'm using =>

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: 'Skus',
      localField: 'style_id',
      foreignField: 'style_id',
      pipeline: [
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            style_id: 0,
            sku_id: 0,
          },
        },
      ],
      as: 'skus',
    },
  },
  { $out: 'Styles' }
```

What I'm doing is pulling in each sku object from another collection using $lookup, then $out the resulting $skus array to the Styles collection. Is there another way to do this that results in a skus object rather than an array? Another step I can add to the agg. process? I've tried using $arrayToObject but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

`$arrayToObject` seems like a reasonable approach to accomplish your goal. The key to making it work is to generate the new field names (`"0"`, `"1"`, etc) first. Approaches to that which came to mind for me were to use [the `$range` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) or [the `$indexOfArray` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/). Example playgrounds demonstrating these approaches are [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rc_KQz8dsrs) and [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/V41i4QdpWnA). The first should probably be preferred as it would be more correct in general I think. (The latter would have problems with duplicate entries in the array, which I don't think would be relevant to this particular situation but noting for completeness anyway.)

There are some details missing from the question which are important for the overall answer. As far as I can tell, the array that you have currently is the result of the `$lookup` in your aggregation (as opposed to having the documents stored that way to begin with). If so then you'll want to insert the `$addFields` stage demonstrated above between the `$lookup` and `$out` in your existing pipeline.

But more broadly, what's the motivation for this operation and change? Some potentially relevant things to keep in mind:

- `$out` overwrites a collection if it exists already. It's not clear what the `Styles` collection is or how you intend to use it, but perhaps consider `$merge` instead.
- Using dynamic field names like this generally makes querying and accessing the data more difficult and less efficient. I would certainly recommend making sure that you can effectively work with your proposed format before going too far down that road.
- You can use the general `array[index]` syntax in a variety of contexts when working with the existing array format. This includes most client drivers/applications. And while not something I'm necessarily recommending, there is some general support for syntax like `skus.2.productName` within MongoDB, see [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lxaq2cpz-Lg).
- There are a variety of [Array Expression Operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#array-expression-operators) built-in to MongoDB for you to take advantage of.

In short - approaches to solve the question you asked are contained in the playground links at the top of this answer. But there are some important additional considerations to keep in mind before implementing the solution as-is.

Comment: Thank you a ton. I'm new to the aggregation pipeline and purposely left my question enough to get an answer but vague enough to get the answer you proposed. I especially appreciate the 'things to consider you left'.

Comment: Follow up...after the process proposed in the first example above, which did exactly what I was hoping, turning an embedded array to an embedded object. In the process shown in the first example. The objects in the sku object take on the form -->

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful.  Looks like your follow-up question here in the comments may have been cut-off? Might be worth a new question? Either way, hopefully the existing comment helped answer the original question posed here.